# Join 2 table in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I need help on this issue as i don't have any experience in Power Bi. I want to join 2 table in Power Bi where it have the same column which is Part_Number. How can i make this 2 table to match by Part Number and return the value?

**Recon Table**

[image]

Inventory Table

[image]

I would like to have **Part Number, Part Name, QTY, Total Quantity** as the result. Hope that i can the clarification i need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide sample data as text and not images.

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like you researched this at all. [This is in Microsoft's documentation.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9) Also, please provide sample data, not pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case you simply must merge the tables. It doesn't look like you have done a lot of research on the matter though, so it's hard to understand exactly what you need help with.

To merge your two tables in Power Query, I would right click in the left hand side menu and select `Merge Queries as New`.

[image]

After that you simply follow the on-screen instructions and select your two tables and their respective key columns. After merging you can choose to disable load of your two original tables to save space in your data model, but this depends on your requirements.

If this was **my** data model, I would think on why joining these tables are necessary, instead of using these two tables as fact tables, and creating a third table to handle the part number dimension with associated part metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs: [Merge queries in Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9)